# Sanitize HTML data received from CKEditor getData() method [ckeditor]

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I want to get sanitized data from CKEditor when I use `CKEDITOR.instances['textareaId'].getData();` function.

I have noticed CKEditor internally sanitized the input provided in the 'Source' part.

**Example**

- If the input is `<p onclick="alert('document.cookie')">Some Text</p>` it gets converted to `<p>Some Text</p>`.
- But when I try to retrive the data using `CKEDITOR.instances['textareaId'].getData();` it returns `<p onclick="alert('document.cookie')">Some Text</p>`.

Is there any way where CKEditor sanitize the data when `getData()` function is called?

Comment: I am using CKEditor4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From CKEditor point of view don't disable Advanced Content Filter (ACF) - don't use `config.allowedContent = true;`. That way unwanted HTML attribute will be removed.

Please note however that JavaScript, no matter how good, can always be disabled so ACF by no means can be treated as a security filter. If you wish to sanitize your HTML, please use server-side library for that and not JavaScript. Sanitizing user input with your server-side application code is the only correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this, just after your ckeditor cdn link

```
<script>
 CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
</script>
```